# undefined is not a function (evaluating 'a(b.apply(undefined, arguments))')

Tags: react-native

what happen with this error?
I dont know what to do, I have remove node_modules and npm install again, it doesn't work. what should I do?

[image]

Comment: Try to provide some code and we might be able to find the problem

Comment: I don't know wich code I should provide, because I got it on github and so many code

Comment: I mean, whatever you can to provide. Something that we can debug, otherwise it's impossible

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - in your Store do you reference REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION?

If so, you will want to remove this from your code as the redux dev tools extension wont work for a native app.